# Kafka Streams Processor API batching on size and time

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Trying to batch the records using kafka streams processor API. Batching is based on size and time. Lets say if the batch size reaches 10 or the last batch is processed more than 10 secs ago (Size or last processed time what ever comes first)  then call external API to send the batch and commit using ProcessingContext.

Using `punctuate` to periodically check if the batch can be cleared and send to the external system.

**Question** - Can the processor API `process` method be invoked by streams API when the punctuate thread is being executed? Since the code is calling commit in punctuate thread can the `context.commit()` commit records which are not yet processed by process method?

Is it possible that the punctuate thread and process method being executed at the same time in different threads? If so then the code I have commit records which are not processed yet

```
public class TestProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, String> {

    private ProcessorContext context;
    private List<String> batchList = new LinkedList<>();
    private AtomicLong lastProcessedTime = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        LOG.info("Calling init method " + context.taskId());
        this.context = context;
        context.schedule(10000, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (timestamp) -> {
            if(batchList.size() > 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastProcessedTime.get() >
                    10000){
                //call external API
                batchList.clear();
                lastProcessedTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            context.commit();
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        batchList.add(value);
        LOG.info("Context details " + context.taskId() + " " + context.partition() + " " +
                "storeSize " + batchList.size());
        if(batchList.size() == 10){
            //call external API to send the batch
            batchList.clear();
            lastProcessedTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        context.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if(batchList.size() > 0){
            //call external API to send the left over records
            batchList.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the processor API `process` method be invoked by streams API when
>   the `punctuate` thread is being executed?

nope, it's not possible, as `Processor` executes `process` and `punctuate` methods in a single thread (the same thread used for both methods).

> Is it possible that the punctuate thread and process method being
>   executed at the same time in different threads?

response is 'it's not possible', description provided above.

take into consideration that each topic partition will have own instance of your class `TestProcessor`. instead of local variables `batchList` and `lastProcessedTime` I recommend to use Kafka state store like `KeyValueStore`, so your stream will be fault tolerant.

Comment: Thanks Vasily for the response.


 I Just need some clarification your last statement about using KeyValueStore. If you see the code i am specifically committing the offset using context after processing each batch. I have set the commit interval to Long.max_value for the same reason.

So even if the sytem crashes stream would stream the data from the point where it was last committed. Do you see any problem of loosing data with this approach  and still suggest using keyvaluestore??

Comment: with your current implementation, you will lose messages. on each invocation of `process`, you trigger `commit`. suppose that you stored into `batchList ` 5 items, and your app crashed, so you will lose these 5 messages. with key-value store you don't need to commit by yourself.

Comment: Even if the process crashed i dont think we would lose 5 messages. Since the context is not ocmmitted next time new process runs it should pick them up

Comment: Kafka Streams makes offset commits by itself automatically at appropriate time, and additionally, you also trigger `context.commit()` which does not guarantee that it will be done immediately. so your implementation is error prone. 

at the end of your `process` method, you trigger commit for each message. if you already processed 5 messages, and application was restarted, these 5 messages will be lost in case commit was applied.